# LINQ - filtering, grouping and getting Min and Max value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Let's say that I have an EF entity class that represents some value in time:

```
public class Point
{
    public DateTime DT {get; set;}
    public decimal Value {get; set;}
}
```

I have also a class that represents some time period:

```
public class Period
{
    public DateTime Begin {get; set;}
    public DateTime End {get; set;}
}
```

Then I have an array of `Period`'s that can contain some specific time slices, let's say that it looks like (`Period` objects are always in ascending order in the array):

```
var periodSlices = new Period [] 
{
    new Period { Begin = new DateTime(2016, 10, 1), End = new DateTime(2016, 10, 15)},
    new Period { Begin = new DateTime(2016, 10, 16), End = new DateTime(2016, 10, 20)},
    new Period { Begin = new DateTime(2016, 10, 21), End = new DateTime(2016, 12, 30)}
};
```

Now, using LINQ to SQL how to write a query which would filter out and group the `Point`'s with oldest(min) and latest(max) values within each of `periodSlices`, so in this example scenario a results should have a 3 groups with min and max points (if any of course).

So what I need to have as a result is something like `IQueryable<Period, IEnumerable<Point>>`.

Right now I am doing it this way, but the performance is not the greatest:

```
using (var context = new EfDbContext())
{
    var periodBegin = periodSlices[0].Begin;
    var periodEnd = periodSlices[periodSlices.Length - 1].End;

     var dbPoints = context.Points.Where(p => p.DT >= periodBegin && p.DT <= periodEnd).ToArray();

    foreach (var slice in periodSlices)
    {
        var points = dbPoints.Where(p => p.DT >= slice.Begin && p.DT <= slice.End);

        if (points.Any())
        {
            var latestValue = points.MaxBy(u => u.DT).Value;
            var earliestValue = points.MinBy(u => u.DT).Value;
        }
    }   
}
```

Performance is crucial (the faster the better as I need to filter out and group ~100k of points).

Comment: If there are lot of items in you collections, you could use Parallel.ForEach, it may improve the speed

Comment: A query this complex is not ideal for EF as it is impossible for the framework to generate an optimized query this complex. There are two things you could do: 1) Create a stored procedure you can call with EF. 2) _Maybe_ create a view to query against to find the min and max, but I think if you're looking for 3 sets of data, you'll most likely need to query it 3 times, making it not ideal.

Comment: In your example, why are you iterating over `periodSlices`? You're just running the same code 3 times regardless of the value of `slice`.

Comment: @Rotem, I have updated the code

Comment: The same, sorry I wanted to shorten the code - now it is fixed

Comment: What is the usual or maximum number of records in the `periodSlices` array?

Comment: always below 50

Comment: Last question, what is the average number of results that are returned from the initial min/max filter in the `periodSlices` array where you still notice that the code is slow?

Comment: `dbPoints` can have max of 100k results, then `points` for each of `slice` can have up to 50k records - ususally it differs depending on the time span the `slice` presents

Comment: The best thing to do in this case is to not do any type of pre-filtering. Go right into your loop and format your query so you execute 1 select for each `slice` in your loop. That should leave you with 50 db queries. If you have trouble merging the min/max to get value it would be 100 queries. If you notice this is slow then it could be due to a missing index on the `Points` table that can be taken advantage of, in that case profile the DB server and capture the exact query being sent and use that to construct the missing index. 100 db calls should still be relatively fast.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that

Comment: Do you really need `IQueryable<Period, IEnumerable<Point>>` or something like `IQueryable<Period, MinDT, MaxDT>` would be sufficient? In other words, do you need the actual `Point`s per `Period` or just Min/Max date.

Comment: To be exact, for each of `periodSlices` I need to have two `Points` (if they exist of course) - one which is the earliest and one which is the latest within the specified time period. That is because I cannot be sure that points in db are always ordered by `DateTime` - if they will, I would need only the `Value` part - min and max.

Comment: I have tested mutiple methods and so far the one I am using right now - despite the fact that it maybe is stupid to store in memory 50k points just to get two of them - has best performance. I would be great if I could do the same without need to store whole data in memory.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a single SQL query solution:

```
var baseQueries = periodSlices
    .Select(slice => db.Points
        .Select(p => new { Period = new Period { Begin = slice.Begin, End = slice.End }, p.DT })
        .Where(p => p.DT >= p.Period.Begin && p.DT <= p.Period.End)
    );

var unionQuery = baseQueries
    .Aggregate(Queryable.Concat);

var periodQuery = unionQuery
    .GroupBy(p => p.Period)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Period = g.Key,
        MinDT = g.Min(p => p.DT),
        MaxDT = g.Max(p => p.DT),
    });

var finalQuery =
    from p in periodQuery
    join pMin in db.Points on p.MinDT equals pMin.DT
    join pMax in db.Points on p.MaxDT equals pMax.DT
    select new
    {
        Period = p.Period,
        EarliestPoint = pMin,
        LatestPoint = pMax,
    };
```

I've separated the LINQ query parts into separate variables just for readability. To get the result, only the final query should be executed:

```
var result = finalQuery.ToList();
```

Basically we build a `UNION ALL` query for each slice, then determine the minimum and maximum dates fro each period, and finally get the corresponding values for these date. I've used `join` instead of the "typical" `OrderBy(Descending)` + `FirstOrDefault()` inside the grouping because the later generates terrible SQL.

Now, the main question. I can't say if this would be faster than the original approach - it depends on whether the `DT` column is indexed and the count of `periodSlices` because each slice adds another `UNION ALL SELECT` from source table in the query, which for 3 slices looks like this

```
SELECT
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [C1],
    [GroupBy1].[K2] AS [C2],
    [GroupBy1].[K3] AS [C3],
    [Extent4].[DT] AS [DT],
    [Extent4].[Value] AS [Value],
    [Extent5].[DT] AS [DT1],
    [Extent5].[Value] AS [Value1]
    FROM    (SELECT
        [UnionAll2].[C1] AS [K1],
        [UnionAll2].[C2] AS [K2],
        [UnionAll2].[C3] AS [K3],
        MIN([UnionAll2].[DT]) AS [A1],
        MAX([UnionAll2].[DT]) AS [A2]
        FROM  (SELECT
            1 AS [C1],
            @p__linq__0 AS [C2],
            @p__linq__1 AS [C3],
            [Extent1].[DT] AS [DT]
            FROM [dbo].[Point] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[DT] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[DT] <= @p__linq__1)
        UNION ALL
            SELECT
            1 AS [C1],
            @p__linq__2 AS [C2],
            @p__linq__3 AS [C3],
            [Extent2].[DT] AS [DT]
            FROM [dbo].[Point] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE ([Extent2].[DT] >= @p__linq__2) AND ([Extent2].[DT] <= @p__linq__3)
        UNION ALL
            SELECT
            1 AS [C1],
            @p__linq__4 AS [C2],
            @p__linq__5 AS [C3],
            [Extent3].[DT] AS [DT]
            FROM [dbo].[Point] AS [Extent3]
            WHERE ([Extent3].[DT] >= @p__linq__4) AND ([Extent3].[DT] <= @p__linq__5)) AS [UnionAll2]
        GROUP BY [UnionAll2].[C1], [UnionAll2].[C2], [UnionAll2].[C3] ) AS [GroupBy1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Point] AS [Extent4] ON [GroupBy1].[A1] = [Extent4].[DT]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Point] AS [Extent5] ON [GroupBy1].[A2] = [Extent5].[DT]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it soon. Right now, `DT` column is not indexed, I will create an index for it, but I am just worried that it would affect the 'write' performance for `Points` table.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the earliest (min) and latest (max) point in each time slice, the first thing I would look at is getting the database to do more.

When you call .ToArray() it brings all the selected points into memory. This is pointless as you only want 2 per slice. So if you did somehting like:

```
foreach (var slice in periodSlices)
{
    var q = context
                .Points
                .Where(p => p.DT >= slice.Begin && p.DT <= slice.End)
                .OrderBy(x => x.DT);
    var min = q.FirstOrDefault();
    var max = q.LastOrDefault();
}
```

It *might* work better

I say *might* because it depends on what indexes there are on the database and how many points are in each slice. Ultimately to get really good performance you may have to add an index on the datetime, or, change the structure so the min and max are pre-stored, or do it in a stored proc.

Comment: I have tried similar approach earlier, performance is quite the same

Comment: In addition as far as I know, `LastOrDefault` is not supported in LINQ to SQL. Thus, I would need to sort the data twice : ascending and get FirstOrDefault and then descending and get FirstOrDefault